# How to Extract the zip file in C#.net in framework 4

Tags: c#, zip, gzip

I need to extract the zip file and read the file contents. .zip file not supported till framework 4. But i should need to extract from zip file in framework 4. Already i tried some third party (eg Sharpziplib) But this not supported for framwork 4.

I tried with another solution using .gz file to compress and decompress. But i could not able to do that also. I am getting gzip length not supported when decompress it. When i compress this file it was compress as individual file not single file as zip. I don't know .gz is same as zip.

Anyone can explain.

Comment: I use Ionic.Zip http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/ works for .Net 4

Comment: SharpZipLib is support in any version of .NET 2.0 and above.  What makes you say it's not supported in .NET 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharpZipLib is a pretty ubiquitous archiving library used by most c# programmers:

http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://zipstorer.codeplex.com/ is a good solution in a single cs file.